# Entity Framework – Many to many mapping with a large number of items

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

In my application I’ve two tables with a many to many mapping, Foo and Bar:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid FooId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

}

public class Bar
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

}
```

At one point I need to add a lot (about 10’000) bars to a foo record.
The bar records already exist in the database and I’ve stored the ids of the bar records in the memory.
Now I’m looking for a fast way to create a mapping between the Foo record and all the bar records.

So far I tried to create new bar entities based on the ids stored in the memory and using the *DbContext.Entry* method to set their state to Unchanged:

```
var barIds = new List<Guid>();  
var bars = barIds.Select( x => new Bar { BarId = x } );
bars.ForEach( x => barRepository.Entry( x ).State = EntityState.Unchanged );
var foo = new Foo
{
    Bars = bars
};
fooRepository.Add(foo);
fooRepository.SaveChanges();
```

This works, but is very slow (Calling Entry for each entity takes a lot of time).
Is there a more performant way to do this using EF?

Comment: But you don't need to call `Entry` method in this case, just create your list of bars and related them with the new `Foo`, add the foo to its `DbSet`, call `SaveChanges` and that's it

Comment: I’ve I don’t set the state for each entity, EF gives me a validation error. 
Bar has some required properties… and it seems EF does validate each entity if the state is not set to unchanged.

Comment: But setting required fields is a requirement to save a entity in your DB. That's not a bad behavior, you should create those entities setting the required fields with default values

Comment: That’s correct. BUT the bar records do already exist in the DB (with valid values). I want to create a new Foo entity and create a mapping to some already existing Bar records. And instead of loading all the Bar records from the DB, I like to create the mapping using the Bar-ids I’ve stored in the memory.